# How to redirect based on this condition using .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Currently i am using the below .htaccess for removing the .php extension

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

I want to show the page `www.example.com/login.php` when typing `www.example.com/login` and want to show `www.example.com/profile=username` when typing `www.example.com/username`

Any suggestion or answers thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.9lessons.info/2009/11/pretty-urls-with-htaccess-file.html

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?key=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?key=$1

<?php

$key=$_GET['key'];

if($key=='home')
{
include('home.php'); // Home page
}
else if($key=='login')
{
include('login.php'); // Login page
} 
else if($key=='terms')
{
include('terms.php'); // Terms page
}
else 
{
include('users.php'); // Users Gateway
}
?>
```

Comment: If i type www.example.com/login will it redirect to imdex.php?key=login ?

Comment: yeah i think but you have to define that code in php file, i edited my code check it! you can see that tutorial! i don't know much about .htacess files!

Comment: I already created login pages...using this .htaccess will make me recreate all that pages....

Comment: nah you just have to add this to index.php page!

Comment: it just redirects to page!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/([\w]+)\.php [NC]

#Select ONE of the following options and DELETE the others
# 1) Without redirection
RewriteRule .*  %1/%2 [L]

# 2) With temporary redirection
RewriteRule .*  %1/%2 [R,L]

# 3) With permanent redirection
RewriteRule .*  %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

Select the rewrite rule accordingly.

Comment: plz can u say what it does?

Comment: Well, it captures the URI and separates it into 2 groups: First one with the whole path until the php file. Second one with the name of the file. Finally, the rewrite rule uses those 2 groups to assemble the substitution URL.

Comment: It doesn't redirect. Just does what you asked for: Remove the `.php` extension. If you want it to redirect, just replace the [L] with [R,L] for a temporary redirection or with [R=301,L] for a permanent redirection.

Comment: Can u plz give me the code...When typing /login should show /login.php page and when typing /username then redirect to profile?username=username thanks

Comment: Its not working...when typing /index.php its redirecting to /index and showing 404 not found

Comment: The rules in the answer will work as you asked in your question. Now you are asking for a different behavior. It's ok, there is no problem, but I suggest you update your question with some complete examples making clear which is the URL for the resource, what URL will be shown in the browser address bar and what's the requested URL.

Comment: Some NOTES: Resource URL is the address to the script (xx.php) that process the request. The `requested` URL is the one entered initially  in the browser address bar and the URL to show is the `substitution` URL, the one displayed in the browser address bar after the redirection, if any.